# Django override auth_views.logout

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to figure out how I can override the auth_views.logout method. Normally I wouldn't have a problem doing this with regard to overriding class methods, however I've realised I'm trying override a view, is this possible to do in Django?

The reason why I want to override the view is so I can include a message via messages.add_message that says 'You are signed out'. Initially it was redirecting to a logout template, however I wanted to make it so when somebody logs out it redirects to the login page, I am currently doing this via next_page in auth.urls.py

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def my_logout(request):
     # message user or whatever
     return auth_views.logout(request)
```

Then, hook up `my_logout` in your urls.py instead of the default `auth_views.logout`. (Of course you can change the name of the view to whatever).

Comment: You can easily do this with CBVs, as well. See answer for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Oops, I just re-read the part where you say you need to do a redirect. Chris's answer will be able to handle redirection.

---

For django 1.3, there is a logout signal which is documented specifically for this purpose.

> The auth framework uses two signals that can be used for notification when a user logs in or out.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#login-and-logout-signals

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_out

def logout_notifier(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
    messages.add_message(request, 'Thanks for logging out!')

user_logged_out.connect(logout_notifier)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Chris Pratt's idea as CBV, and then hook up in your URLConf:

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout    

class LogoutView(View):

    template_name = 'registration/logged_out.html'

    def get(self, request):
        response = logout(request)

        return render(response, self.template_name)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    . . .
    url(r'^logout/$', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout')
    . . .
]
```